# Halva smells like play-dough? a common ingredient?

Tags: flour, pastry

I tried a Halva (gound sesame and sugar kind of sesame marzipan) of a kind I didn't try before, and I find it smells like Play-dough. My wife says that when she makes Play-dough from flour it also has the 'Play-dough' smell. Could there be a common ingredient to the two? Maybe cream of tartar? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it was a sesame based Halva? [Halva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halva) generally falls in to two wide varieties, one flour based and the other nut based. I would assume that the smell of play-dough comes from the flour. So it's possible you had a flour based one.

BTW, it's wikipedia that's defining Tahini as being nut based, I'm not so sure about that classification myself.

Comment: *Nut-butter-based* - which is a valid term IMO.  Peanut butter is classified as a "nut butter" even though peanuts are technically not nuts.

Comment: yes it was Tahini based (Sesame Seeds), no flour in the ingredient list